# How to persist local storage after a logout in React-admin?

Tags: javascript, cookies, react-admin

So I have to save some user preferences and I wanted to use the [useStore](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/useStore.html) hook to do so. As per the [Preference](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Store.html) documentation states:

> The store uses the browser local storage (or a memory storage when localStorage isn’t available). The store is emptied when the user logs out.

Is there a way to avoid this and preserve some of the saved preferences after the user logs out?

I tried to go around React-admins functionality and created functions that access the store directly, but seems that react-admin deletes even the data that he did not write (quite aggressive?). Currently I don't want to store this data on the backend (Not an option), so the only other way is cookies I believe. I want to avoid cookies if possible since I would have to comply with the "[ePrivacy Directive](https://gdpr.eu/cookies/)". Is there a way around React-admin's functionality or another option that I don't see or don't know about?

Comment: Judging by the source texts, react-admin removes from localStorage only entries whose identifier begins: 'RaStore' 
https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/blob/master/packages/ra-core/src/store/localStorageStore.ts

Comment: @MaxAlex you are right. After further investigation, I have found that some of our internal packages are clashing with react-admin and clearing the whole localStorage instead of just entries that start with 'RaStore'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @MaxAlex stated react-admin deletes only entries that start with 'RaStore'. The problem was with some of our internal components reacting weirdly with react-admin and therefore clearing the whole localStorage.